# How to compile ogre4j under linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, compilation, ogre3d

I've download sources and imported then into eclipse. But when i try to run it, it prints error that ogre4j isn't found. I've looked into folder where should be library binaries, but there was nothing. I tried to compile it on my own, not automatic with eclipse, but i haven't found any makefile.

Is there any plugin required for ogre4k compiling?

Where can i find any makefile for ogre4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Joachims reply i've used ant. But there was two steps, which i've did.
In projects directory:

```
mkdir sdk
ln -s /usr/include/OGRE sdk/include
ln -s /usr/lib/OGRE sdk/lib
```

And modify build.xml, add these lines:

```
<property name="env.JAVA_HOME" value="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun" />
<property name="env.OGRE_HOME" value="sdk"/>
```

And finally run:

```
ant ogre4j.build.c
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the projects [Installation Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/ogre4j/wiki/Installation) there is an ant `build.xml` provided and `ogre4j.build.jar` is the target you're interested in.

So running `ant ogre4j.build.jar` in the project directory should build everything that's needed (provided you've got [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) installed).

In Eclipse right-clicking the `build.xml` and choosing "Run As" -> "Ant Build ..." should allow you to select the target and run it.

Comment: org.ogre4j_1.6.2.jar is created, but native libraries aren't compiled